# WCF Client Mocking with RhinoMock

Tags: c#, wcf, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to mock a WCF Client Proxy with Rhino Mock but I am not having much luck.

```
    var ServiceMock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<ServiceClient>();
    ServiceMock.Expect(p => p.Publish("")).IgnoreArguments().Return("Worked");
```

This is how I have been trying to mock the proxy out. It is a normal set up through a constructor.

This does not seem to mock the ServiceClient can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to use Rhino mocks with WCF

http://kashfarooq.wordpress.com/2008/11/29/mocking-wcf-services-with-rhinomocks/ and 
http://ayende.com/blog/2095/wcf-mocking-and-ioc-oh-my

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass{

private IService _service;

[TestInitialize]
public void Setup(){
_service = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IService, ICommunicationObject>();
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestWhatsGoingOn(){

_service.Expect(.....).Return(.....);

//This will test the close is called too (hence the ICommunicationObject above)
((ICommunicationObject)_service).Expect(r => r.Close());
}

[TestCleanup]
public void CleanItUp{
_service.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

This means you can test the close method is called too (as expected)

I think you need to generate a strict mock not a partial...

Also of course, if you want to assert that the .Abort() call is made during exception handling and the like - you can do so with:

```
((ICommunicationObject)_service).Expect(r => r.Abort());
```